# How to prove when electron spin is perpendicular to linear momentum, orbital angular momentum can't be 0

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, angular-momentum

And when they are paralleled, orbital angular momentum is 0.

Comment: Explain what you mean with the electron spin being perpendicular. Electron spin can not be perpendicular to any direction, as there is no $m_s=0$.

Comment: I mean the spin-quantization axis.

Comment: sorry...but the last question has been totally neglected...